# Sending Nested NSMutableDictionary as parameters for POST request in AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsmutabledictionary, afnetworking-3

I am trying to send nested mutable dictionary as parameters in POST request in AFNetworking 3.0.

Here is my sessionmanager settings :

```
self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

The dictionary is prepared as below:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
    NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:self.userMobNoTf.text];

    NSString *UDID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    NSMutableDictionary *miniDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [miniDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"ID"];
    [miniDict setObject:self.userIDTf.text forKey:@"UserId"];
    [miniDict setObject:self.userNameTf.text forKey:@"Name"];
    [miniDict setObject:self.userPasswordTf.text forKey:@"Password"];
    [miniDict setObject:UDID forKey:@"IMEI"];
    [miniDict setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"AppVersion"];
    [miniDict setObject:self.userNameTf.text forKey:@"CreatedBy"];
    [miniDict setObject:myNumber forKey:@"MobileNo"];
    [miniDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"isActive"];

    NSMutableDictionary *paramDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [paramDict setObject:self.userNameTf.text forKey:@"UserName"];
    [paramDict setObject:self.userPasswordTf.text forKey:@"Password"];
    [paramDict setObject:self.userIDTf.text forKey:@"UserId"];
    [paramDict setObject:myNumber forKey:@"MobileNo"];
    [paramDict setObject:UDID forKey:@"Imei"];
    [paramDict setObject:[miniDict mutableCopy] forKey:@"Food_UserLogin"];
```

Here is the POST request:

```
[appD.sessionManager POST:@"FoodSignUpSave" parameters:paramDict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [radialHUD dismiss];
        });

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [radialHUD dismiss];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    }];
```

However, I am getting below error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x174660fc0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x174241bc0 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}
```

If I don't send miniDict in key "Food_UserLogin", I am getting success response but putting this parameter as it being a dictionary creates problem. Any suggestions as to what is wrong?

P.S. I won't want to make any changes on server side.

Comment: Out of interest, why does it need to be mutable?

Comment: I read somewhere that for it to convert in proper json string , one needs to send a mutable dictionary

Comment: And how is JSON related to your question?

Comment: request needs to have parameters in json for acceptablity at server. That is why I am using AFJsonRequestSeriazer.

Comment: Doesn't the serializer need to be set on the session manager rather than `self` though?

Comment: Yes, It can be set on sessionmanager object itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107705/discussion-between-tech-savvy-and-trojanfoe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by converting miniDict to JSONString and sending this JSONString as value in "Food_UserLogin".

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:miniDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[paramDict setObject:jsonString forKey:@"Food_UserLogin"];
```